# How do I tell angular to scan the DOM after using AJAX to insert new content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've working on a project that uses AJAX to load content, and would like to load a bit of content that will be developed using AngularJS.  After I load the content in via AJAX, it just sits there -- Angular doesn't recognize the angular directives I've added.  How do I get AngularJS to scan the new code and process it?

```
var ajaxLoad = function(obj){
  $('.target').load('dynamiclyDeterminedHTMLTarget',function(response, status, xhr){
    //Target HTML is loaded, but not parsed by Angular
  });
}
```

Edit:

For complete clarity, I'm actually *loading* the angular content inside this call.  The controller is *inside* the ajax content.  See below.

```
<div class='ajax-loaded-content'>
    <div ng-controller='MyNewCtrl'>
        {{ this_should_be_compiled_but_isn't }}
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm working on a 'legacy' project that doesn't use angular, and I'm trying to inject angular into it because that -- to me -- makes the most sense.

Comment: Maybe post some code we can look at?

Comment: Done, @DanielCottone.  It was such a small tidbit of code didn't really think it was needed, but I suppose it's useful context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After receiving an HTML response via AJAX, use the [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service to compile/link the template against some scope.

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', '$compile', '$element', '$http',
  function ($scope, $compile, $element, $http) {
    $http.get('dynamiclyDeterminedHTMLTarget').then(function (res) {
       // inject the DOM content
       $element.html(res.data);

       // compile/link element contents
       $compile($element.contents())($scope);
    });
  }
]);
```

Alternatively, you can hand off the AJAX request to the [`ngInclude`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) directive, which will take care of loading, compiling, linking, and injecting the content into the DOM.

```
<div ng-include="dynamicallyDeterminedHTMLTarget"></div>
<!-- (provided the scope has a "dynamicallyDeterminedHTMLTarget" property) -->
```

---

If you initiate the request outside of the Angular lifecycle, you can [bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap) the dynamic content as a stand-alone Angular app.

```
$('#target').load('dynamicallyDeterminedHTMLTarget', function() {
  angular.bootstrap(this, ['myApp']);
});
```

Comment: See my edit -- I don't have access to a controller until after I add it via ajax.  This is a legacy project that I'm injecting angular into because it's the easiest way to implement a new feature.

Comment: You can always create an outer controller responsible only for loading in the contents. Otherwise, you can use your content as the root of your Angular app. Check out [`angular.boostrap`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap).

Comment: While I understand this is a quick and dirty solution, don't use Angular Controllers to manipulate the DOM, I also wouldn't use a controller to make a direct ajax call.

Comment: @m.e.conroy, agreed. Between the first two solutions, I prefer `ngInclude`.

Comment: Angular.bootstrap was exactly the solution I was overlooking, thank you!